# Typescript: isComposing does not exist on type Event

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In a React app with Typescript i get a Typescript error during compile time and in the editor:

```
TS2339: Property isComposing does not exist on type Event
```

This happens on an OnChange event in a HTML Input, which is defined like this:

```
import { InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react';

export interface TypingState {
  inputProps: InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;
}

inputProps: {
  onChange: (e) => handleInput(e.target.value, e.nativeEvent.isComposing)
}
```

Why is the property `isComposing` not existing on the nativeEvent?
In the Browser console the property is present and the code is working.

In the types definition the generic type `HTMLInputElement` is passed to the onChange handler.

```
onChange?: ChangeEventHandler<T> | undefined;
```

Is HTMLInputElement maybe the wrong type here?

[Example code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgSQHZgK4wBIBUCyAMgIIwxTABGWApgM5wC%20cAZlBCHAORQ0CGAYxhcA3ACgxNAB6RYcYKhg0oLQTTi4AnmAUBzAMow%20SxGLjz0WAArswdAFwpLOAiTIVqSugB48RNJgwAKIANjQgNIoAfOKMEgIQqHTwCoG49DCOWjqoBkYmALym5uap1rYOxSUliQDCABZ8uTSOABQ0AJRwBVFwCUkQYQB0IRC67UNGULo0MEMAbnwhGDQANHA0Q6jGwPM0QXuKQ8B0tRyQdHodZiVxjCJAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged the value of `e.nativeEvent` inside the Codesandbox and it logged an instance of `InputEvent` constructor. so, you can type-gaurd using the constructor like this:

```
if(e.nativeEvent instanceof InputEvent) {
    e.nativeEvent.isComposing; // works as expected
}
```

Comment: I found that typecast work as well: `(e.nativeEvent as InputEvent).isComposing)` but your solution is probably more typesafe because of the check.